# Error in install Kali Linux tool with Katoonlin

Tags: 18.04, katoolin

I am trying to install Kali Linux tool on Ubuntu 18.04 using [Katoolin](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin). when I **Add Kali Linux repositories** it show me

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the exact commands you ran to add the repository and the exact output the commands gave.

Comment: it is a commin issue with first installs of kali. Simple solution: add the GPG Key... https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18079-Public-key-error

Answer (score 0):

Update the GPG key from archive.kali.org. Open the terminal and type:

```
wget -q -O - archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | apt-key add  
and sudo apt update
```